# Understanding ko.mapping.fromJSON

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that uses WebAPI for data, and KnockOutJS on the front end. For the most part, things work pretty well, however I started to realize that when updating values, those values are not being reflected in the bound elements.

The reason for this is because the data is being passed from the server as JSON, and being converted in a plain JSON object. In other words, no properties are being mapped as "observables", so when I change the values of the object, nothing gets updated.

I read about a plugin for KnockOutJS called "mapping" which I have added, however I can't quite figure out the correct syntax to make it work. I'm hoping someone else has dealt with this and has some suggestions. Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function BlogViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.blogs = ko.observableArray();
        var baseUri = '@ViewBag.ApiUrl';

        //$.getJSON(baseUri, self.blogs);
        $.getJSON(baseUri, {},
                function (data) {
                    ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, self.blogs);
                });
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new BlogViewModel());
    });

    });
</script>
```

The commented out portion ($.getJSON(baseUri, self.blogs);) is what used to be there, and "works" in regard to getting and displaying the data.

The code just below that is my attempt to read the data in and apply the mapping to it. It is not working at all. In other words, I am not seeing any data on the page.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Looking back in time and saw your question...did you find what you were looking for? If so, post your answer!

Comment: I have the same problem. It happens at sometimes an object has been updated on a server-side. After I received a result to view so I need to fire DOM update. Have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Map your JSON data to ko viewmodel like this:

```
ko.mapping.fromJSON(data, {}, self.blogs);
```